# Unsure about result given in lecture

Tags: normal-distribution, definition

I'm looking through my notes and something my lecture said seems off, just want to clarify.

"Let $Z_1,\ldots, Z_n$ be iid N(0,1) random variables and let $\overline{Z}$ be their average. Then $\overline{Z}$ is normal with mean 0 and deviation $\frac{1}{n}$. So

$$\frac{\overline{Z}-0}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=\sqrt{n}\overline{Z}$$ is N(0,1). Is this true? would it not be that the variance of $\overline{Z}$ would be $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Variance of $\bar{Z}$ *is* $1/n$.

Comment: Thank you so mistake was "deviation $\frac{1}{n}$" but everything else is correct?

Comment: Unless 'deviation' is another way of saying variance there is no mistake.

Comment: but he says deviation is $\frac{1}{n}$ but you say variance is $\frac{1}{n}.$ So he did make a mistake and wrote deviation when he meant to write variance I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have found an error in your notes. Most likely, your lecturer meant to say “and variance $\frac{1}{n}$” or “and standard deviation $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.”